# Picking random numbers from an array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, random, complexity-theory, permutation

Is it possible to pick M unique uniformly random elements from an array of size N in O(M) time?

A O(N) solution is obviously trivial, eg. Fisher-Yates a size N array and truncate to the first M elements.

Comment: You don't need a full F-Y. You can truncate a F-Y shuffle after M times through the loop. If M is very small compared to N, you might also consider Floyd's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a random number in [0,x) for each x in [n-m,n]. For each random number, swap the item at that index with the item at the index of the upper bound. Something like:

```py
import random

def random_elements(items, count):
    length = len(items)

    for i in range(count):
        index = random.randrange(0, length - i)
        yield items[index]
        items[length - i - 1], items[index] = items[index], items[length - i - 1]
```

Comment: but isnt this a O(n2) complexity level?

Comment: @s.d: Is it? I’m assuming `randrange` and array access are O(1).

Comment: oh ya , Array size is reducing each time. Good +1

Comment: Wouldn't this produce side effects on the array n?

Comment: @JasonSperske: Yes, but I think it’s possible to keep another map of swapped indices and stay O(m) (though cloning would mostly be faster in practice).